# How to generate all permutations of an array in sorted order?

Tags: c++, permutation

I have an array, and the user can insert a string.

And I have this code:

```
int main(){
  char anagrama[13];
  cin >> anagrama;
  for(int j = 0; j < strlen(anagrama); j++){
    cout << anagrama[j];
    for(int k = 0; k < strlen(anagrama); k++){
      if(j != k)
        cout << anagrama[k];
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
}
```

The problem is that I need all **permutations** of the string in **sorted** order.

For example if the user write: `abc`, the output must to be:

```
abc
acb
bac
bca
cab
cba
```

and my code doesn't show all permutations, and not sorted

Can you help me?

I need do the implementation without a function already implemented.

I think with a recursive function, but I do not know how.

This is an example: 
http://www.disfrutalasmatematicas.com/combinatoria/combinaciones-permutaciones-calculadora.html  without repetition and sorted

Comment: Given the "without a function already implemented" implies homework, so I won't give full code. Yes you can use recursion. Iterate through the characters in the string, each time removing that character so it can pass the still-unused characters in a call to itself. A reasonable function signature would be `void f(std::vector<std::string>& results, const std::string& unused_chars, const std::string& prefix_so_far = "")`. If `f` finds `unused_chars` empty, it can add the `prefix_so_far` to `results`.

Comment: Combinations are different from permutations(your example). In combinations, order of the elements doesn't matter,the order do matter in permutations.

Comment: push all combination into vector and then sort it.

Answer (score 54):

In C++ you can use [`std::next_permutation`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) to go through permutations one by one. You need to sort the characters alphabetically before calling `std::next_permutation` for the first time:

```
cin>>anagrama;
int len = strlen(anagrama);
sort(anagrama, anagrama+len);
do {
    cout << anagrama << endl;
} while (next_permutation(anagrama, anagrama+len));
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/dElvE2).

If you must implement permutations yourself, you could [borrow the source code](http://wordaligned.org/articles/next-permutation) of `next_permutation`, or choose a simpler way of implementing a permutation algorithm recursively.

Comment: Not, i need implement the permutation, i can not use a function

Comment: I intent implementing a permutation algorithm recursively, but i have some problems

Answer (score 14):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void permute(string select, string remain){
    if(remain == ""){
        cout << select << endl;
        return;
    }
    for(int i=0;remain[i];++i){
        string wk(remain);
        permute(select + remain[i], wk.erase(i, 1));
    }
}

int main(){
    string anagrama;
    cout << "input character set >";
    cin >> anagrama;
    sort(anagrama.begin(), anagrama.end());
    permute("", anagrama);
}
```

---

Another version

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void permute(string& list, int level, vector<string>& v){
    if(level == list.size()){
        v.push_back(list);
        return;
    }
    for(int i=level;list[i];++i){
        swap(list[level], list[i]);
        permute(list, level + 1, v);
        swap(list[level], list[i]);
    }
}

int main(){
    string anagrama;
    vector<string> v;
    cout << "input character set >";
    cin >> anagrama;
    permute(anagrama, 0, v);
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
}
```

Comment: Ok, but what is string (wk). What does this function?

Comment: And How I can sort the output?

Comment: @AlexanderOvalle `wk(remain)` constructor. remain copy to wk.

Comment: But i do not understand, Why do I have to declare wc in each cycle?

Comment: `Why do I have to declare wc in each cycle?` to remove the selected element.

Comment: @AlexanderOvalle  `why erase(i,1)? ` E.g `string wk("abc");wk.erase(1,1);//wk:"ac"` `erase(pos, len)` : to erase the element of the length from the specified position.

Comment: @AlexanderOvalle `swap` exchange the specified element. It is exchanged instead of deleting in this version.

Comment: The second version expects an out of bounds `operator[]` to return zero? It is presumably a null terminator, but is that guaranteed? Shouldn't `for(int i=level;list[i];++i){` be `for(int i=level; i < list.length();++i){`?

Answer (score 2):

```
/*Think of this as a tree. The depth of the tree is same as the length of string.
In this code, I am starting from root node " " with level -1. It has as many children as the characters in string. From there onwards, I am pushing all the string characters in stack.
Algo is like this:

1. Put root node in stack.
2. Loop till stack is empty
2.a If backtracking
2.a.1 loop from last of the string character to present depth or level and reconfigure datastruture.
2.b Enter the present char from stack into output char

2.c If this is leaf node, print output and continue with backtracking on.
2.d Else find all the neighbors or children of this node and put it them on stack. */



        class StringEnumerator
        {
        char* m_string;
        int   m_length;
        int   m_nextItr;
        public:
        StringEnumerator(char* str, int length): m_string(new char[length + 1]), m_length(length)  , m_Complete(m_length, false)
        {
        memcpy(m_string, str, length);
        m_string[length] = 0;
        }
    StringEnumerator(const char* str, int length): m_string(new char[length + 1]), m_length(length)  , m_Complete(m_length, false)
    {
        memcpy(m_string, str, length);
        m_string[length] = 0;
    }
    ~StringEnumerator()
    {
        delete []m_string;
    }

    void Enumerate();
   };


        const int MAX_STR_LEN = 1024;
        const int BEGIN_CHAR = 0;

        struct StackElem
        {  
      char Elem;
      int Level;
      StackElem(): Level(0), Elem(0){}
      StackElem(char elem, int level): Elem(elem), Level(level){}

        };

        struct CharNode
        {
      int Max;
      int Curr;
      int Itr;
      CharNode(int max = 0): Max(max), Curr(0), Itr(0){}
      bool IsAvailable(){return (Max > Curr);}
      void Increase()
      {
        if(Curr < Max)
            Curr++;
      }
      void Decrease()
      {
        if(Curr > 0)
            Curr--;
       }
       void PrepareItr()
      {
        Itr = Curr;
       }
};




        void StringEnumerator::Enumerate()
{

    stack<StackElem> CStack;
    int count = 0;
    CStack.push(StackElem(BEGIN_CHAR,-1));
    char answerStr[MAX_STR_LEN];
    memset(answerStr, 0, MAX_STR_LEN);

    bool forwardPath = true;

    typedef std::map<char, CharNode> CharMap;

    typedef CharMap::iterator CharItr;
    typedef std::pair<char, CharNode> CharPair;

    CharMap mCharMap;
    CharItr itr;

    //Prepare Char Map
    for(int i = 0; i < m_length; i++)
    {
        itr = mCharMap.find(m_string[i]);
        if(itr != mCharMap.end())
        {
            itr->second.Max++;
        }
        else
        {
            mCharMap.insert(CharPair(m_string[i], CharNode(1)));
        }
    }


    while(CStack.size() > 0)
    {
        StackElem elem = CStack.top();
        CStack.pop();

        if(elem.Level != -1)     // No root node
        {
            int currl = m_length - 1;
            if(!forwardPath)
            {
                while(currl >= elem.Level)
                {
                    itr = mCharMap.find(answerStr[currl]);
                    if((itr != mCharMap.end()))
                    {
                        itr->second.Decrease();
                    }
                    currl--;
                }

                forwardPath = true;
            }

            answerStr[elem.Level] = elem.Elem;

            itr = mCharMap.find(elem.Elem);
            if((itr != mCharMap.end()))
            {
                itr->second.Increase();
            }
        }

        //If leaf node
        if(elem.Level == (m_length - 1))
        {
            count++;
            cout<<count<<endl;
            cout<<answerStr<<endl;
            forwardPath = false;
            continue;
        }

        itr = mCharMap.begin();

        while(itr != mCharMap.end())
        {
            itr->second.PrepareItr();
            itr++;
        }


        //Find neighbors of this elem 
        for(int i = 0; i < m_length; i++)
        {
            itr = mCharMap.find(m_string[i]);
            if(/*(itr != mCharMap.end()) &&*/ (itr->second.Itr < itr->second.Max))
            {
                CStack.push(StackElem(m_string[i], elem.Level + 1));
                itr->second.Itr++;
            }
        }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

@alexander the output of this programme is in exact order as requested by you:

HERE, is a simplest code for generating all combination/permutations of a given array without including some special libraries (only **iostream.h** and **string** are included) and without using some special namespaces than usual ( only **namespace std** is used).

```
void shuffle_string_algo( string ark )
{

//generating multi-dimentional array:

char** alpha = new char*[ark.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < ark.length(); i++)
    alpha[i] = new char[ark.length()];

//populating given string combinations over multi-dimentional array
for (int i = 0; i < ark.length(); i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < ark.length(); j++)
        for (int n = 0; n < ark.length(); n++)
            if( (j+n) <= 2 * (ark.length() -1) )
                if( i == j-n)
                    alpha[i][j] = ark[n];
                else if( (i-n)== j)
                    alpha[i][j] = ark[ ark.length() - n];

if(ark.length()>=2)
{
    for(int i=0; i<ark.length() ; i++)
    {
        char* shuffle_this_also = new char(ark.length());
        int j=0;
        //storing first digit in golobal array ma
        ma[v] = alpha[i][j];

        //getting the remaning string
        for (; j < ark.length(); j++)
            if( (j+1)<ark.length())
                shuffle_this_also[j] = alpha[i][j+1];
            else
                break;
        shuffle_this_also[j]='\0';

        //converting to string
        string send_this(shuffle_this_also);

        //checking if further combinations exist or not
        if(send_this.length()>=2)
        {
            //review the logic to get the working idea of v++ and v--
            v++;
            shuffle_string_algo( send_this);
            v--;
        }
        else
        {
            //if, further combinations are not possiable print these combinations 
            ma[v] = alpha[i][0];
            ma[++v] = alpha[i][1];
            ma[++v] = '\0';
            v=v-2;

            string disply(ma);
            cout<<++permutaioning<<":\t"<<disply<<endl;
        }
    }
}
}
```

and **main**:

```
int main()
{
string a;
int ch;
do
{
    system("CLS");
    cout<<"PERMUNATING BY ARK's ALGORITH"<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter string: ";
    fflush(stdin);
    getline(cin, a);

    ma = new char[a.length()];

    shuffle_string_algo(a);

    cout<<"Do you want another Permutation?? (1/0): ";
    cin>>ch;
} while (ch!=0);

return 0;
}
```

HOPE! it helps you! if you are having problem with understanding logic just comment below and i will edit.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote one without a function already implemented even any templates and containers. actually it was written in C first, but has been transform to C++.

easy to understand but poor efficiency, and its output is what you want, sorted.

```
#include <iostream>
#define N 4
using namespace std;

char ch[] = "abcd";

int func(int n) {
    int i,j;
    char temp;
    if(n==0) {
        for(j=N-1;j>=0;j--)
            cout<<ch[j];
        cout<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        temp = ch[i];
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
            ch[j-1] = ch[j];
        ch[n-1] = temp;
        //shift
        func(n-1);
        for(j=n-1;j>i;j--)
            ch[j] = ch[j-1];
        ch[i] = temp;
        //and shift back agian
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    func(N);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: not so easy to understand when compared to standard library functions..

Answer (score 1):

In case you have std::vector of strings then you can 'permute' the vector items as below.

**C++14 Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/join.hpp>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    std::vector<std::string> s;
    s.push_back("abc");
    s.push_back("def");
    s.push_back("ghi");

    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());
    do
    {
      std::cout << boost::algorithm::join(s,"_") << std::endl ;
    } while(std::next_permutation(s.begin(), s.end())); 
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

abc_def_ghi

abc_ghi_def

def_abc_ghi

def_ghi_abc

ghi_abc_def

ghi_def_abc