# Generate all "without-replacement" subsets series

Tags: combinatorics, pseudocode

I'm looking for a way to generate all possible subcombinations of a set, where each element can be used at most one time.

For example, the set `{1,2,3}` would yield

```
{{1},{2},{3}}
{{1},{2,3}}
{{1,2},{3}}
{{2},{1,3}}
{{1,2,3}}
```

A pseudocode hint would be great. Also, if there is a term for this, or a terminology that applies, I would love to learn it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a few pointers.

The separation of a set into disjoint subsets is called a set partition ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set), [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SetPartition.html)).

A common way to encode a set partition is a [restricted growth string](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RestrictedGrowthString.html).

The number of set partitions is a [Bell number](http://oeis.org/A000110), and they grow fast: for a set of 20 elements, there are 51,724,158,235,372 set partitions.

---

Here is how encoding works.
Look at the elements in increasing order: 1, 2, 3, 4, ... .
Let `c` be the current number of subsets, initially `0`.
Whenever the current element is the lowest element of its subset, we assign this set the number `c`, and then increase `c` by 1.
Regardless, we write down the number of the subset which contains the current element.

It follows from the procedure that the first element of the string will be `0`, and each next element is no greater than the maximum so far plus one. Hence the name, "restricted growth strings".

---

For example, consider the partition `{1,3},{2,5},{4}`.

Element `1` is the lowest in its subset, so subset `{1,3}` is labeled by `0`.
Element `2` is the lowest in its subset, so subset `{2,5}` is labeled by `1`.
Element `3` is in the subset already labeled by `0`.
Element `4` is the lowest in its subset, so subset `{4}` is labeled by `2`.
Element `5` is in the subset already labeled by `1`.

Thus we get the string `01021`.
The string tells us:

Element `1` is in subset `0`.
Element `2` is in subset `1`.
Element `3` is in subset `0`.
Element `4` is in subset `2`.
Element `5` is in subset `1`.

---

To get a feel of it from a different angle, here are all partitions of a four-element set, along with the respective reduced growth strings:

```
0000      {1,2,3,4}
0001      {1,2,3},{4}
0010      {1,2,4},{3}
0011      {1,2},{3,4}
0012      {1,2},{3},{4}
0100      {1,3,4},{2}
0101      {1,3},{2,4}
0102      {1,3},{2},{4}
0110      {1,4},{2,3}
0111      {1},{2,3,4}
0112      {1},{2,3},{4}
0120      {1,4},{2},{3}
0121      {1},{2,4},{3}
0122      {1},{2},{3,4}
0123      {1},{2},{3},{4}
```

---

As for pseudocode, it's relatively straightforward to generate all such strings.
We do it recursively.
Maintain the value `c`, assign every number from `0` to `c` inclusive to the current position, and for each such choice, recursively construct the rest of the string.
Also it is possible to generate them lazily, starting with a string with all zeroes and repeatedly finding the lexicographically next such string, akin to how `next_permutation` is used to [list all permutations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17396248/1488799).

Lastly, if you'd like to see more than that (along with the mentioned `next` function), here's a bit of self-promotion.
Recently, we did a learning project at my university, which required the students to implement various functions for combinatorial objects with reasonable efficiency.
[Here](https://github.com/spbsu-student-projects/combinatorial-objects/blob/master/restricted_growth_string/restricted_growth_string.h) is the part we got for restricted growth strings; I linked the header part which describes the functions in English.